# How to reuse a drive in which windows was installed before

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, uninstall

I was using Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 as dual boot. I just uninstalled windows completely. Windows was in sda2 (type:ext3). Now I can't use this drive (it's empty and not writeable). How I can use this drive?

Comment: How was Windows installed on an ext3 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that there is already a partition formatted with ext3. So till now you just need to mount this partition to use it.

create a mounting point suppose /media/ext-hdd

```
sudo mkdir /media/ext-hdd
```

now mount the partition to that point

```
sudo mount -t ext3 /de3v/sda2 /media/ext-hdd
```

Now if you want to make auto mount this partition you have to add it to the `/etc/fstab` file.

first identify the UId of this partition

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda2
```

Now open `fstab`

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Add the following

```
UUID=YOUR_UID /media/ext-hdd    ext3    defaults    0   0
```

save and exit

Comment: running the first command i get " mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/ext-hdd’: File exists  "

Comment: this means the folder already exists, then you can just skip this step

Comment: do i need to reboot for using that drive? the drive is still write protected,[i didn't reboot]

Comment: Why not just format the drive? It'll automount then.

Comment: Can you please say, how i can be expert at linux terminal command? I just search google> copy the codes>paste in terminal. But I dont understand meaning of these codes. In case of programing language I know what i am writing, but i dont know what commands i am writing in terminal., How can i learn linux command like a programing language?

Comment: you just need more practice, work and try whatever you face and within time you can get used to. also always use `man` pages. informative