# "The disk drive for /media/ext-hdd is not ready yet or not present" is shown every boot time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I used ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.1 as dual boot. windows was in sda2 drive. I removed windows and sda2 drive became empty which was not writeable. I was able to write in that drive following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628832/how-to-reuse-a-drive-in-which-windows-was-installed-before/628835#628835).

**Now problem is that** every time I boot PC i face

> The disk drive for /media/ext-hdd is not ready yet or not present
>
> Continue to wait, or Press s to skip mounting or M for manuall recovery

How to get rid of this message?

Note that, running this command:

> EDITOR=gedit sudoedit /etc/fstab

the file is opened contains:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name     devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=254c94fe-8270-48f4-8e0e-eaea3e1e724f /               ext4        errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=e1fba1b7-c6fa-4321-b69f-302e428200c9 /home           ext4        defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=2a74858d-7f8c-4c12-a365-d1bf9291b4ae none            swap        sw              0       0
UUID=YOUR_UID /media/ext-hdd    ext3    defaults    0   0
```

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot) should solve your problem. Always search before posting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and type:

```
EDITOR=gedit sudoedit /etc/fstab
```

Locate the line which contains your Windows partition and comment it out (prepend a `#`):

```
#UUID=YOUR_UID /media/ext-hdd    ext3    defaults    0   0
```

Reboot, and Ubuntu should stop complaining about it not being present.

Comment: i have edited my question, hope it will be more clear.

Comment: Updated my answer, just comment out the last line

Comment: BTW, does it literally say 'YOUR_UID' or did you just replace the actual value with that?

Comment: I didn't get your last comment but its now solved. Great help !!

Comment: Glad to help you